# Using Max() with other field with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table in SQL SERVER:

```
CREATE TABLE cats
(
       name VARCHAR(10),
       breed   VARCHAR(25),
       weight decimal(8,2),
       color  VARCHAR(25),
       age int
)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Ashes','Persian',4.5,'Black',5)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Molly','Persian',4.2,'Black',1)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Felix','Persian',5.0,'Tortoiseshell',2)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Smudge','British Shorthair',4.9,'Black',4)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Tigger','British Shorthair',3.8,'Tortoiseshell',2)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Alfie','Siamese',5.5,'Brown',5)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Oscar','Siamese',6.1,'Black',1)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Millie','Maine Coon',5.4,'Tortoiseshell',5)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Misty','Maine Coon',5.7,'Brown',2)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Puss','Maine Coon',5.1,'Tortoiseshell',2)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Smokey','Maine Coon',6.1,'Brown',4)
INSERT INTO @cats VALUES('Charlie','British Shorthair',4.8,'Black',4)
```

I need for each (color) to select\view the oldest cat, and it's name.
It's very easy to use `GROUP BY color` but the problem is when you add the name everything is missed up.

I think I should use `OVER()`, `Partition BY` or `RANK()`/`DENSE_RANK`... I tried them all but I got stuck. please help me with this.

Thanks !

Comment: "I tried them all but I got stuck" - with what? Please, show what did you try so far and what was wrong with it

Answer (score 2):

here is one way:

```
select * from (
   select *, row_number() over(partition by color order by age desc) rn from cats
) t where rn = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c3f7a908fbc12f18e0bc9f6713c9e707)*

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using a correlated subquery:

Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/798bd7/3.

```
select 
  (select top 1 name from cats c 
    where c.age = tmp.maxage 
          and c.color = tmp.color) name,
  color, 
  maxage
from (
  select color, max(age) as maxage
  from cats
  group by color
) tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    color
    , [max] = max(age) over (partition by color)
FROM cats
```